# I want to count the CourseName like(4,2,5) in "Numbers Of Courses" column, but the output is being displayed full courseName

Tags: mysql, oracle

I want to display the full names of faculty members and the number of courses they are currently teaching.

My query is:

```
SELECT CONCAT( FName, ' ', LName ) AS "Faculty Names", course.CourseName AS 'NUmbers Of Courses'
FROM Faculty LEFT JOIN course ON (course.FacultyID = faculty.FacultyID) 
ORDER BY faculty.FacultyID`
```

Question 1:  I want to count the CourseName like(4,2,5) in the "Numbers Of Courses" column, but the output being displayed is the full courseName.

Question 2:  Using a left join in the "Numbers Of Courses" column, some rows have Null values, but I want to show 0 there, instead.

[image: Tables picture here.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`. Check this -

```
SELECT CONCAT( FName, ' ', LName ) AS "Faculty Names",
COUNT(course.CourseName) AS 'NUmbers Of Courses', faculty.FacultyID
FROM Faculty 
LEFT JOIN course ON (course.FacultyID = faculty.FacultyID) 
GROUP BY faculty.FacultyID, "Faculty Names"
ORDER BY faculty.FacultyID
```

> Note : You should include FacultyID while `GROUP BY`, because, you never can be sure that you will not have same `FName` + `LName` for any 2 Facultes.